# iFraming an mht file

Tags: javascript, iframe, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

So I have a suite of reports that when you select a button at the top it moves to a new report that is being ran by jQuery. Each of these reports are iFramed in. I want to iFrame a MHT file into the suites but when I select the button with the MHT file in it, it opens up a new window, which I do now want. I have tried some javascript to where it doesn't open in a new window but rather the same window using _self in the code. that doesn't work either. any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using cognos 10.2.1 on IE9. My company won't change their web browser that they use so that is not an option. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. So I have the URL in the folder structure for the MHT file and it wouldn't work. I ran the MHT file and the URL it gave me from there is what I used to iFrame it in and it worked. Hope that makes sense and I hope it helps someone out there who may need it.